# Firestore + cloud function: What does { merge: true } do?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to write my first cloud function with Firestore. In a lot of questions/articles, people recommend adding "{ merge: true }". What does that do? Where can I read more about it.

My background is in Java. This may be a JavaScript fundamental. A pointer in the right direction of documentation/article would be much appreciated.

Here is an example for a cloud function for Firestore:

```
exports.updateLikeCount2 = functions.firestore
    .document('likes/{likeId}').onWrite((event) => {
      admin.firestore.collections('ruleSets').document(ruleSetId).get().then(doc => {
                admin.firestore.document('ruleSets/' + ruleSetId).set({likeCount2: oldCount}, { merge: true });
```

What does adding/removing { merge: true } do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) is your friend. From there:

> **Options**
>
> An object to configure the set behavior. Pass `{merge: true}` to only replace the values specified in the data argument. Fields omitted will remain untouched.

Comment: Ah! That's where it is! I was getting lost in the documentation: Android reference, admin reference, functions reference! I thought it was something in JavaScript  itself. Awesome!